# "Missing php5ts.dll" error when installing Saxon/C

Tags: php, dll, saxon

I'm trying to install Saxon/C (beta version 0.3.1) on a Windows 7 machine but after following [the instructions](http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/index.html), when I attempt to restart PHP a Windows dialog box pops up saying;

`The program can't start because php5ts.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this error.`

Followed by;

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_saxon.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`

I'm using;

- Windows 7 32-bit
- PHP 5.4.27 (Thread Safety disabled)
- nginx 1.4.6

I start PHP from the command prompt by doing;

```
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

If I remove the reference to Saxon `extension=php_saxon.dll` from `php.ini` then PHP starts OK but obviously the Saxon/C extension won't work. If I put the reference back into `php.ini` then the errors appear.

It's as if Saxon/C is expecting PHP to be running in thread-safe mode, however the Saxon documentation implies that it should work with both thread-safe and non thread-safe;

> The Saxon/C dll library is a 32-bit version. The PHP extension dll was
>   compiled for PHP version 5.4 (TS/NTS).

Comment: Update: It seems to work OK with the thread-safe version of PHP 5.4.45

Comment: Update 2: Error `missing php5ts.dll` with the non thread-safe version of PHP 5.4.45. Maybe it only works in thread-safe mode.